# Using sudo in LXC containers for accounts without valid shell

Tags: command-line, 16.04, sudo, lxc

For accounts, in containers, that have no shell (e.g. user www-data) I'd like to use sudo, without ending up in /root/ folder.

Why does this only work after using it for the second time ?
How can I avoid ending up in /root/ dir with sudo ?

```
$ sudo lxc-attach -n hugo
root@hugo:~# sudo -H -u golanger /bin/bash && cd /home/golanger
golanger@hugo:/root$
golanger@hugo:/root$ exit
root@hugo:/home/golanger# sudo -H -u golanger /bin/bash && cd /home/golanger
golanger@hugo:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sudo -H -u golanger /bin/bash && cd /home/golanger`, your current shell executes `sudo -H -u golanger /bin/bash` and when that finishes successfully, runs `cd /home/golanger`. So the `cd` doesn't affect the `sudo` command.

`sudo` itself doesn't reset the working directory (`-H` only resets the home directory, not the current working directory). If you want to make `sudo` `cd` to the home directory of the target user, there are no command-line options which can directly do the job. You'll have to workaround it:

```
sudo -H -u golanger /bin/sh -c 'cd; /bin/bash'
```

Note that, with the `-i` option, `sudo` will try to `cd` to the home directory of the target user, but it also uses the user's login shell, which will make it fail in this case.